# Why doesn't data bing use LiveData or Observable fields?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

In my mind, One-way or Two-way data bing use either `LiveData` or `Observable fields`.

The following code is from the project https://github.com/enpassio/Databinding

The attribute `android:text="@={viewModel.toyBeingModified.toyName}"` of the control `android:id="@+id/toyNameEditText"` bind to `viewModel.toyBeingModified.toyName` with Two-way data bing.

I'm very strange why `viewModel.toyBeingModified` is neither `LiveData` or `Observable fields`, could you tell me?

**fragment_add_toy.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data class="AddToyBinding">

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.enpassion.twowaydatabindingkotlin.viewmodel.AddToyViewModel" />

        <import type="com.enpassion.twowaydatabindingkotlin.utils.BindingUtils"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_standard">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_standard"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/skin_rose"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
            app:contentPadding="@dimen/padding_standard"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                ...

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toyNameLayout"
                    style="@style/Widget.Enpassio.TextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/toy_name"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineET"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="418dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/toyNameEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:text="@={viewModel.toyBeingModified.toyName}"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        ...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**AddToyViewModel.kt**

```
class AddToyViewModel(private val mRepo: ToyRepository, private val chosenToy: ToyEntry?) : ViewModel() {

    val toyBeingModified: ToyEntry

    private var mIsEdit: Boolean = false

    init {
        if (chosenToy != null) {
            //This is edit case
            toyBeingModified = chosenToy.copy()
            mIsEdit = true           
        } else {
            /*This is for adding a new toy. We initialize a ToyEntry with default or null values
            This is because two-way databinding in the AddToyFragment is designed to
            register changes automatically, but it will need a toy object to register those changes.*/
            toyBeingModified = emptyToy
            mIsEdit = false          
        }
    }

    private fun insertToy(toy: ToyEntry) {
        mRepo.insertToy(toy)
    }
    ...
}
```

**ToyEntry.kt**

```
data class ToyEntry(
    var toyName: String,
    var categories: Map<String, Boolean>,
    var gender: Gender = Gender.UNISEX,
    var procurementType: ProcurementType? = null,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val toyId: Int = 0
): Parcelable{

    /*This function is needed for a healthy comparison of two items,
    particularly for detecting changes in the contents of the map.
    Native copy method of the data class assign a map with same reference
    to the copied item, so equals() method cannot detect changes in the content.*/
    fun copy() : ToyEntry{
        val newCategories = mutableMapOf<String, Boolean>()
        newCategories.putAll(categories)
        return ToyEntry(toyName, newCategories, gender, procurementType, toyId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, we use LiveData or Observable fields when we need to do something as soon as they changed, search bar can be a good example. But in this case, we don't care when the user is changing the properties of the selected toy (I haven't seen the UI but I'm assuming there is a Save button or something like that). In other words, we don't want to do anything while user is typing `b`, `bo`, `boa` and finally `boat`.

We just need that data to be once set while the viewmodel is set to binding, let the user change it to whatever and when we want to do the saving process, we want our field to be what user had entered.
In addition, if you use LiveData in your binding (as long as the lifecycleOwner is set) you're adding an observer to you LiveData which can be a point of concern for some geeks .

**TL;DR**

We use LiveData when we want to observe it (which is not required in the example you provided). It's an option not a must. Data binding can set/get data for nearly everything.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start with 1-way data binding first and as soon as this works, extend it to 2-way data binding. What you are doing wrong right now is the following:

```
android:text="@={viewModel.toyBeingModified.toyName}"
```

This line of code means that you pass a `ToyEntry` object to a `setText()` method of the TextView. That means the `TextView` would need to have a method with the signature: `setText(entry: ToyEntry)`.

Of course, this method does not exist (yet). So to make this data binding work, you have to define this method yourself by creating a `BindingAdapter`:

```
@BindingAdapter("toyEntry")
fun setToyEntry(textView: TextView, toyEntry: ToyEntry) {
   // in here you define what to do with the textView. For example:
   textView.text = toyEntry.toyName
}
```

- You can create this BindingAdapter in any file without the need to put it into a class.
- You can give this method any name you want
- The first parameter of this method is the kind of View in the xml that you want to bind the toyEntry to
- The second parameter of this method os the object that you set in your xml via `@{...}`

Now when you write a 1-way databinding like this: `binding:toyEntry="@{viewModel.toyBeingModified.toyName}"`

- The `binding` namespace can be craeted by AndroidStudio automatically. You can name this anything you want (but not `android`, since this is already defined)
- The `toyEntry` is what connects this line of xml to your BindingAdapter from the previous step (it corresponds to the same string that you set in the annotation `@BindingAdapter(...)`

Now, the generated code knows about your binding adapter and calls its method `setToyEntry` when it computes this data binding. You can also delete the line `android:text="@={viewModel.toyBeingModified.toyName}"`, because it is not used anymore.

Go from there to setup 2-way data binding. Here you also have to create `@InverseBindingAdapter` as explained here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter

Some more comments: Depending on your gradle version, you have to enable databinding and also make sure to have all dependencies and gradle plugins setup.
More on that here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/databinding?hl=en